# Confused as to how this step in a number theory proof is performed

Tags: sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory, divisor-sum

How does this step

$$D(q)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty d(n)q^n$$

Become this step?

\begin{align}
D(q)
    &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m|n}mq^n=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{m|n}mq^n \\
    &=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{m|n}m(q^m+q^{2m}+q^{3m}+\cdots)
\end{align}

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). You should also add in some context. These equations didn't come from nowhere. What's $d(n)$? Are there restrictions on $q$? Where did you see this? etc.

Comment: [Related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_series).

Answer (score 1):

The first $=$ writes $d(n)$ as $\sum_{m|n}m$. The second $=$ reverses the order of summation. The final expression is a misprint, as we shouldn't keep the $\sum_{m|n}$ once we expand the sum over $q^n$ terms as the expression in brackets.